# Replace babel-runtime with polyfill.io

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, polyfills, babel-loader

I'm experimenting with replacing the babel-runtime and babel-plugin-transform-runtime with polyfill.io in my React app. My current webpack configuration is:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src")],
            query: {
                presets: ['env', 'react', 'stage-0'],
                plugins: ['transform-runtime']
            }
        },
```

When I remove the plugins line from the above configuration, the bundle size increases by about 29KB.

Shouldn't the bundle size decrease because I'm removing polyfills from the bundle? What is causing the bundle size to increase?

What would be the correct approach to switch from babel-runtime to polyfill.io?

Answer (score 0):

While the runtime transform can provide polyfills, it also helps save space on a bunch of little helper functions Babel has to inject that can't come from polyfills.  In fact, you can configure the runtime transform to not provide polyfills altogether, and in Babel 7 they actually made that the default.  So you actually want `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` *together* with polyfill.io.

It may seem confusing why the examples below don't count as "polyfills" but they're not using standardized API classes/functions like `Promise` or `Map` that true polyfills can add/monkeypatch into your node environment.

Babel's own explanation: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime#why

For example a simple import default statement

```
import foo from 'bar'
```

Babel has to inject a copy of a helper function in every module that does this:

```
"use strict";

var _bar = _interopRequireDefault(require("bar"));

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { "default": obj }; }
```

But with the runtime transform it can import the implementation of `_interopRequireDefault`, sharing the implementation between all modules:

```
"use strict";

var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");

var _bar = _interopRequireDefault(require("bar"));
```

With Webpack and minification applied, this comes out to a lower cost per module with import statements.

Certain things like object rest spread are more dramatic.  Take this code:

```
const {bar, ...baz} = {}
```

Without the runtime transform, babel has to inline an `_objectWithoutProperties` helper function that's expensive, and isn't provided by any polyfills:

```
"use strict";

function _objectWithoutProperties(source, excluded) { if (source == null) return {}; var target = _objectWithoutPropertiesLoose(source, excluded); var key, i; if (Object.getOwnPropertySymbols) { var sourceSymbolKeys = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(source); for (i = 0; i < sourceSymbolKeys.length; i++) { key = sourceSymbolKeys[i]; if (excluded.indexOf(key) >= 0) continue; if (!Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(source, key)) continue; target[key] = source[key]; } } return target; }

function _objectWithoutPropertiesLoose(source, excluded) { if (source == null) return {}; var target = {}; var sourceKeys = Object.keys(source); var key, i; for (i = 0; i < sourceKeys.length; i++) { key = sourceKeys[i]; if (excluded.indexOf(key) >= 0) continue; target[key] = source[key]; } return target; }

var _ref = {},
    bar = _ref.bar,
    baz = _objectWithoutProperties(_ref, ["bar"]);
```

But with the runtime transform `_objectWithoutProperties` can be shared between everything that uses it:

```
"use strict";

var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");

var _objectWithoutProperties2 = _interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/runtime/helpers/objectWithoutProperties"));

var _ref = {},
    bar = _ref.bar,
    baz = (0, _objectWithoutProperties2["default"])(_ref, ["bar"]);
```